# How to use JQuery to hide radio inputs with values of null or 0? Also, can I apply radio "checked" to the first visible item? JFIDDLE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use Jquery to hide all inputs that have a value of 0 or NULL. I was also wondering if there was a way to apply the checkbox="selected" to the first visible list item, as well as placing the values in a hidden div.

In the example, the second list item should be the only one visble, already checked, and the values should be present in the output divs (that I will hide later).

[JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g21Ltpqm/2/)

HTML

```
        <!-- SCALE FORM (OPEN) -->
<fieldset id="custom-fieldset" class="" style="margin-top: 0px;font-variant: small-caps;letter-spacing: 2px;border-radius: 0px;" data-role="controlgroup">

        <input class="weight1" type="hidden" value="0" >
        <input class="price1" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value=""  checked="checked">
        <label class="price_weight_lable1" style="display: flex;line-height: 35px;" for="radio-choice-v-2a">
        <div style="flex:2;text-indent:20px;">grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$</div>
        </label>

        <input class="weight2" type="hidden" value="1.0" >
        <input class="price2" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="15.00">
        <label class="price_weight_lable1" style="display:flex;line-height: 35px;" for="radio-choice-v-2b">
        <div style="flex:2;text-indent:20px;">1 grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$15</div>
        </label>  

        <input class="weight3" type="hidden" value="0" >
        <input class="price3" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="0">
        <label class="price_weight_lable1" style="display:flex;line-height: 35px;" for="radio-choice-v-2c">
        <div style="flex:2;text-indent:20px;">0grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$0</div>
        </label>

    <input class="weight4" type="hidden" value="" >
        <input class="price4" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2d" value="">
        <label class="price_weight_lable1" style="display:flex;line-height: 35px;" for="radio-choice-v-2d">
        <div style="flex:2;text-indent:20px;">grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$</div>
        </label>

</fieldset>
<!-- SCALE FORM (CLOSED) ---------------->



<br><br>

        <!-- hidden -->

<div  class="price_results"></div>
<div  class="weight_results"></div>
        <!-- hidden -->
```

SCRIPT

```
$('input[type=radio]').val(0 || null).hide();   

$('input[type=radio]').on( 'change', function(el){
    $( '.weight_results' ).text( $(this).parent().prev().val() );
    $( '.price_results' ).text( $(this).val() );
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '.price_results' ).text($(".price1").val() );
    $( '.weight_results' ).text($(".weight1").val() );

}); 

// need all list items 0 or NULL to be Hidden

//need the first-visible/lowest price > than 0 to be checked 

//need the values of the first or lowest inputs value > 0 or NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) together with [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(':radio[value=0], :radio[value=""]').closest('.ui-radio').hide();
$(':radio:visible:first').trigger("click").trigger("click");
```

The [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g21Ltpqm/13/).

Comment: ill probably use this and take another approach for the selection thing

Comment: so i am actually dealing with php vales like this

Comment: <input class="price2" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="<?=$onegram_price?>">   

and I don't think Jquery is picking up the values with this code.  I'll keep trying and let you know

Comment: @AaronTomlinson You can always add another condition  like in [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g21Ltpqm/17/)